# Hyperledger fabric: How to build a chaincode that will do something automatically when condition's fulfilled?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The situation is that some banks will transfer money to some bank accounts every month. I want a chaincode that can check if it is the 15th of every month automatically. If yes, it will do the transaction automatically. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show some research effort instead of directly coming up with the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be some trigger point for the chaincode function to be called. In your case scheduler can be scheduled (at application level) to trigger an event or chaincode function directly on the 15th of every month and the chaincode function does the required transaction.